# Are US-specific questions OK?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are questions that are US-specific on-topic on this site?  (i.e., only relevant to academia in the United States)

(Do people want to see those kinds of questions tagged or marked in any particular way?)

Comment: What would make a question US-centric?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub, a question might be US-specific e.g., because it is only likely to be of interest to US readers, and/or because only US readers are likely to be able to answer it.  Anyway, I think I got my answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, these questions are fine. As of now we're not tagging these questions specifically as such; just indicate the target audience in the question.

Answer (score 6):

US specific questions are fine.  They're frustrating when a question doesn't indicate that it is US specific, when it in fact is.  It is a sign of cultural and institutional arrogance not to indicate the culture of institutional-system for which your question or answer applies.

Ideally, if the site's traffic is high, system specific questions should be tagged to allow users to ignore or favourite tags.

Ideally, we might think about whether each particular question that appears to be system specific, is, in fact a useful opportunity to supply a full answer for all major systems.

Comment: Even worse is, downvoting answers for not being US-centric when the question was, without implying that...