# Academia Community Polls

Tags: discussion, community

Welcome to the academia.SE Community Poll thread! (shamelessly stolen from [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls))

This thread is used for opinion and usage polls around Academia and academia.SE. The poll questions are added as "answers" to this "question". Their answers have been added as comments below them. To participate simply up-vote the comments which apply for you. If there is no suitable answer yet simply add it as comment by yourself. You can't up-vote your own comments but the comment author will be counted manually. Please do not add any other comments to these posts. General comments can be added to this "question".
Rules

### Rules

- Community poll questions are placed as "answer" posts below. Feel free to add your own<sup>1</sup>.
- Answers to these poll questions are placed as "comments" below them. Because this is also an opinion poll subjective questions are welcome.
  <sub>Please do not ask too specific questions and allow for multiple choices and votes, e.g. instead of something like "My absolute favorite for X is .." use something like "For X I often use ...".</sub>
- To participate up-vote the comments which apply for you.
- If required add a new answer as a comment.
  <sub>If applicable hyperlink the entry to allow other users to learn more about it. Feel free to flag comments for moderator attention if they should be modified for some valid reason (wrong/missing hyperlink, etc.)</sub>
- Feel free to up-vote the poll questions ("answer" posts) as well to indicate that you liked the question. This will push the most favorite questions to the top.
- Do not post any other answer posts or comments. Please provide feedback and critic on the [corresponding discussion thread](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/discussion-about-academia-community-polls) instead.

**Some things they learned over at TeX.SX**

- Edits to polls after they started should not change the meaning
- Subjective topics are okay
- Yes/No question are okay

<sup>1</sup> Should you be affected by the "Trivial answer converted to comment" feature simply post a longer dummy text and then edit it down to the correct content.

Comment: Discussion on this post should take place [in its dedicated thread](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/468/discussion-about-academia-community-polls).

Answer (score 19):

which of the following "roles" describes you best?

Comment: A professor (tenured or not)

Comment: A Phd Student     .

Comment: A master's Student

Comment: Undergraduate student

Comment: A Post doctoral researcher

Comment: None of the above

Comment: Non-professor permanent research position

Comment: A librarian (academic or not)

Comment: Researcher in industry.

Answer (score 17):

Are you currently working in Academia (i.e., employed by a university with a primary duty of performing research)?

Comment: Yes  [‌](http://longer)

Comment: No  [‌](http://longer)

Answer (score 14):

Comments on this [answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/437/929) made me curious on our demographics. Which countries have academic systems you are familiar with?

Comment: United States of America

Comment: United Kingdom (GB)

Comment: Sweden (Litet språkexempel)

Comment: France [‌](http://makemelonger)

Comment: Germany (Deutschland)

Comment: New Zealand (Aotearoa =] )

Comment: Netherlands (Nederland)

Comment: Czech Republic .

Comment: Slovak Republic (Slovakia)

Comment: India(Bharat Ganrajya)

Comment: Australia......

Comment: Canada---------

Comment: Denmark--------

Comment: Philippines....

Comment: Switzerland (Schweiz/Suisse/Svizzera/Svizra)

Comment: Croatia (Hrvatska)

Comment: Japan (Nihon, Nippon)

Comment: Italy (Italia  )

Comment: Vietnam (Việt Nam)

Comment: Finland (Torilla tavataan)

Comment: Austria (Oesterreich)

Comment: Singapore (Singapore)

Comment: Mexico---------

Comment: Latin America in general

Comment: Norway  (Norge, Noreg)

Comment: Ireland (Eire, Republic of)

Comment: Spain (España )

Comment: Brazil (Brasil)

Comment: Portugal ------

Answer (score 13):

Comments on this [answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/437/929) made me curious on our demographics. What fields would you consider yourself part of?

Comment: Electrical Engineering

Comment: Biomedical Engineering

Comment: Psychology (all areas)

Comment: Neuroscience research

Comment: Earth Science ()

Comment: Computer Science

Comment: Chemistry [‌](http://longer)

Comment: Chemical engineering/materials science

Comment: Mathematics ( )

Comment: Business management

Comment: Mechanical Engineering

Comment: Education [‌](http://longer)

Comment: Civil Engineering

Comment: Theoretical Physics

Comment: Bioinformatics/Systems Biology

Comment: Geosciences ( )

Comment: Social science .

Comment: Atmospheric Science

Comment: Philosophy ()()

Comment: (Human uses of non-food) Energy

Comment: Physics _______

Comment: History (Humanities, NOT a "social science")

Comment: Biology [in general]

Comment: Applied Physics

Comment: Aerospace Engineering

Comment: Computational Science

Comment: Statistics (applied or theoretical).

Comment: Public Health/Epidemiology

Comment: interdisciplinary

Comment: political science

Comment: Library and information science

Answer (score 13):

Is English your mother tongue?

Comment: Yes [‌](http://longer)

Comment: No [‌](http://longer)

Answer (score 12):

How many publications in peer-reviewed journals have you made in your career?

Comment: None.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 1 to 5.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 6 to 10.     [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 11 to 20.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 21 to 30.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 30 to 50.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 51 to 100.    [‌](http://nonsense)

Comment: 100+    [‌](http://nonsense)

Answer (score 12):

What is your gender?

*Please feel free to add the term you feel most comfortable with.*

Comment: Male...........

Comment: Female..........

Comment: Transgender....

Comment: None of the above / Non-binary.

Answer (score 9):

Are/were you happy in your PhD program?

Comment: Yes, and I graduated

Comment: Yes, and I quit

Comment: No, and I graduated

Comment: No, and I quit.

Comment: I've never entered a PhD program.

Comment: Yes (current PhD student)

Comment: No (current PhD student)

Answer (score 8):

If you are not currently working in Academia, do you have one or more advanced degrees?

(My reasoning behind this poll is whether there are people like me who have been in grad school or worked in academia and are interested in it)

Comment: Yes, master's degree.

Comment: Yes, Ph.D, MD, JD, etc.

Comment: Currently enrolled in an advanced degree program.

Comment: No advanced degree.

Comment: Yes, ABD (all but dissertation)

Answer (score 8):

If you received an email from an author of a new paper, whom you'd had no contact with previously, bringing their new paper to your attention, letting you know that they'd cited one or more of your papers in it, and thanking you for your work, what would be your reaction?

Comment: This hasn't happened to me, but I think I'd be pleased.

Comment: This has happened to me, and I was grateful for the email.

Comment: This hasn't happened to me, but I think I'd be (mildly) annoyed.

Comment: This has happened to me, and I was (mildly) annoyed.

Comment: So many people cite me, that if they all emailed me it would be an email avalanche.

Comment: This hasn't happened to me, but I think it would depend on the author and his/her work.

Answer (score 5):

Did you do a part of PhD studies at another institute (for instance to learn a new method), if so for how long?

Comment: No; I never thought of that

Comment: No; I did not want to, everything was great at my institute

Comment: No; I wanted to but wasn't allowed to

Comment: Yes; for a couple of weeks (1-4 weeks)

Comment: Yes; for a couple of months (1-3 months)

Comment: Yes; in a long-term exchange program (3 months or more)

Comment: Yes, by taking courses at that institute

Comment: No; not yet but I would like to

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as we have more "senior"s than students here on AC.SE ([at least according to the poll](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/474/5674)), and also considering that many nationalities are represented here, I would like to know how important academics think of their titles. In other words, how important do you think it is that people address you with your title at work/uni?

Comment: Not important at all, I don't care

Comment: It is somewhat important, but not a demand/expectation

Comment: It is important, I would expect my students/post-docs to refer to me as Prof/Doctor X

Comment: It is important, I expect the undergrad students to call me with my title, but in research environment it doesn't matter

Comment: It is important, I want everyone to acknowledge my titles

Comment: It is important that people *ignore* my title and address me by name.

Answer (score 5):

What software do you use to manage papers?

Comment: Zotero ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Mendeley ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Docear  ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Just folders in my file system

Comment: JabRef reference manager

Comment: Bibdesk (reference manager)

Comment: Homegrown solution

Answer (score 4):

Which time zone (UTC +/-?) are you in primarily?

Comment: UTC+8 (Asia pacific)

Comment: UTC-7 (Mountain Time/US)

Comment: UTC+1 (Central European Time)

Comment: UTC-5 hours (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: UTC+0 [‌](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8827762#8827762)

Comment: UTC+7 (in Asia)

Comment: UTC-5 (Central Daylight Time/US)

Comment: UTC+5:30(India)

Comment: UTC+3(Djibouti, Africa)

Comment: UTC +10 hours (Eastern Australia Standard Time)

Comment: UTC-6 (Mountain Daylight time, Canada)

Comment: UTC-8 (Pacific Time/US)

Comment: UTC-3 (Brazil) ...

Answer (score 2):

What continent do you currently reside in?

Comment: North America (includes U.S., Canada, Mexico)

Comment: Latin America + Central America (includes Caribbean)

Comment: Europe --------

Comment: Africa --------

Comment: Asia ----------

Comment: Australia (but if you prefer to be included in Asia, please register your objection and I will delete this one)

Comment: No one resides in Antarctica?

Comment: @AriBrodsky I don't believe that no-one in Antarctica wants to waste time on the internet

Answer (score 0):

How many professional societies are you a member of? (Motivation: [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151218/what-fraction-of-scientists-are-members-of-professional-societies-and-or-associa).)

Comment: Two............

Comment: Zero............

Comment: Four............

Comment: (at what point do we make an "answer" that is "X or more"?)