# Are we a "life/arts" community?

Tags: discussion

The new display at the bottom is not very good, in my opinion: I would expect to see "Academia" under "Professional," but that's not even in one of the categories shown in the display below—you have to click through to get to a site where you then have to hunt around to find it. That's not a very good system in my opinion.

But, at the very least, we should list Academia where it makes more sense. But is that "Professional" rather than "Life/Arts?"

Comment: If it's listed in "Life/Arts", I would at least cross-list it in "Science" as well.

Comment: I don't think we get to pick multiple options. Otherwise it should already be there! But I guess we can find out. I'll look into this.

Comment: With respect to Daniel E Shub's answer, I think of being an academic as my profession. I spend my working hours in academia and I continue to improve myself, professionally, as an academic. Life/arts seems more appropriate to hobbies. I would not put this site under 'science' since academia (and this site) is not limited to science. I hope we will have many more members from many more branches than just the sciences.

Comment: Our Academia community is still [listed under life/arts](http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts)... [Professional](http://stackexchange.com/sites#professional) or [Science](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science) are the most suitable categories. Why no request is posted on the main site's meta  to change the website's category?

Answer (score 6):

I have to say that I feel that Professional is a better fit. The reason I say so is that research is our job, and academia is the enveloping name for the network we operate in.

Whether or not being an academic is a lifestyle is an abstract discussion in my opinion. Anyone might feel that their job describes their lifestyle; a banker might feel that banking is not a job but a lifestyle, likewise a construction worker might feel that pouring concrete is way beyond a 9-to-5 job. What is an indisputable fact is that a majority of us are in research as a permanent, or temporary, career path. That alone makes my perspective to Academia.SE a site where professional questions/opinions/experiences are voiced.

That's only my opinion of course.

Answer (score 5):

If we can only get one category, then considering the current content of Academia.SE, it seems we would be a better fit in Science than in Life/Arts.

I agree with Daniel that we should aim at being in both, but if we can select only one, we can point out with this [poll question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/470/102) that people currently involved in the community are mostly scientific.

Comment: As time marches on, I hope we will have many more members from many more branches than just the sciences.

Comment: I think the people arguing against the "Science" moniker are perhaps using a limited definition (perhaps associated with particular fields in the natural and social sciences?). The second paragraph the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science) has some discussion about the differences in the scope of the term in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the full list of categories are:

- Technology
- Culture/Recreation
- Life/Arts
- Science
- Business
- Professional

I think Technology, Culture, and Business would be really bad categories for us. While Science might be a reasonable category for us now, I would hope in the future academia.se will cover more than just the sciences. This leaves, as aeismail points out life/arts and professional. I think life/arts is much better than professional. I do not think of being an academic as my profession as much as my life style.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't think of being an academic as your profession. From the high quality of your answers, I would assume you were a full-time academic.

Comment: @earthling I am a full time academic. My point was that I think of being an academic as being an all encompassing lifestyle.