# How are different disciplines represented on this site?

Tags: discussion, community, users

I am pure mathematician, and my impression (which I'm sure is not unique) from frequenting this site for some time is Academia.SE there seem to be a relatively large number of mathematicians on this site, as compared people from many other disciplines, especially social sciences.  I suspect this is in large part due to a strong mathematical involvement with SE beginning with MathOverflow and to some extent with MathStackExchange.

**Question:** Do we have/can we get any rough estimates of a make-up community by field?

The idea behind this question is to get a more concrete sense of things like how much field-dependent bias there is to various posts on this site, as well as which communities we are serving well and which we are not.

A couple of simple ideas are: parse user profiles/SE network usage and/or look at what discipline tags people use.  (As of now, the top 3 discipline tags by posts are: math (1494), CS (1064), physics (296).)  Perhaps restrict to a weak notion of regular users such as has visited at least once/month for at least 3 out of the last 6 months.

Comment: Have you seen https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/academia-community-polls

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for reminding me!  I had seen that long ago and had even participated in the poll on discipline: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/470/19607

Comment: Still that thread is several years old, and of course the poll is biased to people who use meta.

Comment: @Kimball - this is a meta-worthy topic, we tend to keep this sort of stuff off the main site. That said, it's been quite a while since that poll, and the site has changed a lot. May be worth repeating that poll-style question again.

Comment: I can probably already guess the result of the poll for the field of metrology: 1 user (me) :-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You would be wrong. :-)

Comment: I think it's fair to say that we have a bias towards natural sciences, maths and computer science, and don't have so many arts or humanities people. Not sure about social sciences. It's probably also fair to note that that correlates with the fields that use programming more as part of research. But I'd hesitate to be more specific than that. A repeat of the Really Old Poll would be interesting to me :-)