# Country-Specific Answers

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[A question was UK specific](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100923/how-does-academic-career-progression-work), but I wanted to know if it would be appropriate to ask an identical question but for US universities for a US-Answer.

Comment: It seems to me that only the answer is UK specific, not the question.

Comment: Huh, you are right. Question was not country-specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed [fairly extensively on this site before](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=country+is%3Aquestion). The general accepted practice is to use tags to label questions as specific to a given country. (FWIW, I gave a different answer in [this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/189/73), but that was five years ago when the site was brand new... the times, they are a'changin'.)